# Filter documents where all values of an array meet some criteria in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have documents that look like this:

```
{
  times: [{start: "1461116454242"},{start:"1461116454242"}]
}
```

I want to get all documents where every start time is in the past. This query works when all times are in the future or all are in the past, but fails if only one time is in the future (still matches).

```js
query: {
  filtered: {
    filter: {
      bool: {
        must: [
          {
            nested: {
              path: "times",
              filter: {
                script : {
                  script: "doc['start'].value < now",
                  params: {
                    now: Date.now()
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    query: {
      match_all: {}
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution that I just realized:

```js
query: {
  filtered: {
    filter: {
      bool: {
        must: [
          {
            nested: {
              path: "times",
              filter: {
                "bool": {
                  "must": [
                    {
                      "range": {
                        "times.start": {
                          lt: new Date()
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
          }
        ],
          must_not: [
            {
              nested: {
                path: "times",
                filter: {
                  "bool": {
                    "must": [
                      {
                        "range": {
                          "times.start": {
                            gte: new Date()
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          ]
      }
    },
    query: {
      match_all: {}
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this one:

- `include_in_parent: true` in your mapping:

```
    "times": {
      "type": "nested",
      "include_in_parent": true,
      "properties": {
        "start": {
          "type": "date"
        }
      }
    }
```

- and use the `query_string` syntax, without `nested`:

```
{
  "query": {
    "query": {
      "query_string": {
        "query": "times.start:<=now AND NOT times.start:>now"
      }
    }
  }
}
```